# Azure Active Directory Login

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am complete newbie into Azure Active Directory login and I have tried the MVC 5 app using 'cloud - single organization' authentication.

In my azure account, I've set several users in default active directory folder. Few of them added through the wizard as a 'new user in your organization', which are sourced from Windows Azure Active Directory and few of them to be sourced from actual Microsoft Account.

When I start the app and sign in as one of the sourced from Windows Azure Active Directory, I get login and the app says on the top right corner 'Hello, john.doe@domain.com'

However when I login as one sourced from Microsoft Account, I too get login, but on the top right corner the app says 'Hello, !' without the real account name. Just exclamation mark. I suppose this is not the right behaviour, right?

I am using VS2013 community edition and start the app directly from VS through IIS express.

UPDATE:

It seems that for accounts which are on Azure Active Directory listed as sourced from Microsoft Account, the application is not able to retrieve any info - therefore User.Identity.Name is empty or null. Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi i am also facing the same problem. when i have user type "New user in my organization" everything works fine. but when i have user type= "User with an existing Microsoft account" login works file but i am getting User.Identity.Name= null.. please let me know if you get the solution.

Comment: If bellow answer worked for you then please mark as an answer !

Answer (score 3):

I got the salution :)

Add this block in your global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClaimsIdentity id = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity);
    Claim claim = id.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
    if (claim != null)
    {
        string email = claim.Value;
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email));
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is not idiomatic ASP.NET MVC because it uses Global.asax instead of the OWIN pipeline.